# 「和む」is a common word?

Tags: words, verbs

「[和む]{なごむ}」is a word that you can hear in everyday conversation? Or just in poems or songs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

和む can be safely used in conversations just like other simple wago. You may say 和んだ while you are at an animal cafe or enjoying a 日常系 ("slice-of-life") manga/anime, for example. Some people are too busy to use it in "everyday" conversations, but that's another story.

Comment: You can also see it not too rarely in advertisements ad well as articles/books related to relaxation. Like Naruto said, it’s not used by everybody, but it can be used safely.